# CSS image to full width and center vertically?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble finding a solid answer for this question.  It may have been asked before but I cant find a working solution anywhere.

What I want is to make my image full width 100%, keep aspect ratio and center the image vertically with overflow hidden.

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="myimgurl.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can set the img to 100% width and height and set it's CSS `object-fit` to `cover `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**If you really have to use an `<img>`** :

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="myimgurl.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

*This use of transform; translateY() is a convenient way to center vertically items.*

Live demo (thanks to @dsfq) : 
http://jsfiddle.net/rrLyopxe/

Bonus : **When should you use an img element ? When can you simply put a background ?**

If the image you use as an editorial/informational content, this should be an `<img>` element, so you can provide an alt attribute and a title to add information about it.

If the image is only here for graphical purposes (background, decoration, etc.) this is a case to use background-image property.

Comment: @enguerranws Thanks, this is what I needed! Works perfectly! I really appreciate the help. This has been bugging me for a day or two now.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to use an `<img>`?

```
<div class="img-container"></div>
<style>
.img-container{
    background-image: url('myimg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    /* Don't forget to add height and width,
        Without content, the div won't have any height and with */
    height: 10em; width 10em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a height and width to the .img-container.  Without these, it will look like there is nothing there.